# Dojo Mobile cross platform same UI

Tags: cordova, dojo

I am looking to different UI framework to go with Cordova. I have investigated a few already, but confused about Dojo. I know Dojo is powerful and provides Native UI to the app out of the box. 
But is it possible to force same look and feel across all platforms(iOS/Android/Windows phone) in Dojo (Something like ionic) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible to force the same look. One solution is to not use the deviceTheme module to load your CSS. In that case not automatic theming switch will be performed. Another solutions is to configure deviceTheme to always load a particular theme.

Comment: I had a look at document and found that we can get iPhone.css and other themes from dojox module.